# Add a default text value for an ArrayList parameter in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following code

```
    String str = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEDATA(USER,EMPID,IDNUM,IDDESC) VALUES(?,?,?,?);

    sql.append(str);
    ((ArrayList)parameters).add(user);
    ((ArrayList)parameters).add(empid);
    ((ArrayList)parameters).add(idnum);
    ((ArrayList)parameters).add("EMPLOYEE"-iddesc);
```

I'm trying to add the text `"EMPLOYEE"` before the string `iddesc` and insert it to the database.

String iddesc:

```
String iddesc = empid.substring(Math.max(0, empid.length() - 4));
```

The data that should be inserted to the table would be something like this

```
USER - SAI
EMPID - 123456789
IDNUM - 987456
IDDESC - EMPLOYEE-6789
```

Please can someone help me on how to achieve output.

Comment: Sure that you need those **casts**? Usually that indicates a bad design/architecture. Also, do not use **raw-types**. There is absolutely no reason to use them (except you develop for java versions below 1.5).

Comment: Something like this `((ArrayList)parameters).add("EMPLOYEE-" + iddesc);`